# Jenkins pipeline exception - Docker not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jnlp

I have created GKE cluster and install Jenkins on that cluster. Now i am running pipeline, i have Jenkinsfile created which is used to build DockerImage but when i am running the pipeline, it throws exception that Docker not found

1) Created GKE Cluster
2) Installed Jenkins
3) Added Docker hub credentials
4) Added access key for gitlab

Jenkinsfile:

stage('Build Docker Image') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Before docker run'
                    sh 'docker --version'
                    app = docker.build("sarab321/test-pipeline")
                    echo 'docker run successfully'
                }
            }
        }

Please see the exception below

apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    jenkins: "slave"
    jenkins/cd-jenkins-slave: "true"
  name: "default-d7qdb"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "59c323186a77b4be015362977ec64e4838001b6d77c0f372bec7cda7cf93f9b2"
    - "default-d7qdb"
    env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "59c323186a77b4be015362977ec64e4838001b6d77c0f372bec7cda7cf93f9b2"
    - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
      value: "cd-jenkins-agent:50000"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "default-d7qdb"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "default-d7qdb"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "http://cd-jenkins.default.svc.cluster.local:8080"
    image: "jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1"
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "512Mi"
        cpu: "1"
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    securityContext:
      privileged: false
    tty: false
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
      name: "volume-0"
      readOnly: false
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
  nodeSelector: {}
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  serviceAccount: "default"
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: "/var/run/docker.sock"
    name: "volume-0"
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"

- docker version
  /home/jenkins/workspace/TestPipeline_master@tmp/durable-5dd73d2b/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/workspace/TestPipeline_master@tmp/durable-5dd73d2b/script.sh: docker: not found

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like `docker` is installed on your build agent, that's inside the container using the "jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1" image. I have examples of how I've installed the docker CLI in the jenkins LTS image at: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker

That image includes the following steps to make the docker integration portable:

- installs the Docker CLI
- installs gosu (needed since the entrypoint will start as root)
- configures the jenkins user to be a member of the docker group
- includes an entrypoint that adjusts to docker GID to match that of the /var/run/docker.sock GID

The actual docker CLI install is performed in the following lines:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add - \
 && add-apt-repository \
     "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
     $(lsb_release -cs) \
     stable" \
 && apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    docker-ce-cli${DOCKER_CLI_VERSION}
```

You can take the entrypoint.sh and Dockerfile, modify the base image (FROM) of the Dockerfile, and the original entrypoint script inside entrypoint.sh, to point to the jnlp-slave equivalents.

Comment: HI, I have taken the complete code from the git repository you mention and try to run Jenkins pipeline .I placed my own Jenkinsfile, still it fail with Docker not found